# Generic methods T extends

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I want to do something like that:

```
public final <T>T getObject(Class <T extends MyObject> myObjectClass){
    //...
}
```

IDE complains about syntax error. How to write this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the generic type bound in the wrong place.

It should be declared within the declaration of the generic type parameter:

```
public final <T extends MyObject> T getObject(Class<T> myObjectClass)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.